# Command line arguments without full directory

Tags: python, sys

I'm starting to learn python and I'm having problem with command line arguments

Here is the code I'm working with

```
#!python3
# mapIt.py gets the address from command line or clipboard and searches Google with it

import pyperclip, webbrowser, sys

if len(sys.argv)>1:
    #Get address from command line.
    address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    #Get address from copy pasta
    address = pyperclip.paste()

webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address)`
```

When I put in the command line the following nothing happens:

mapIt 123 King St. New York **OR** mapIt.py 123 King St. New York

But if I do this it works:

C:\Users\file1\file2\file3\Python\Scripts\mapIt.py 123 King St. New York

Can't figure out how to solve this. The tutorial only puts the file name and argument and it works. How can I do this too?

Comment: In the first case you didn't use `mapIt.py` Also assuming you're running this from inside the same directory.

Comment: Does running the `.py` file without the folder and without command line arguments work for you? If not, then your problem isn't command line arguments at all

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for pointing that out. I actually tried both mapIt and mapIt.py variations and both didn't work

Comment: @OferSadan I tried both ways. I have updated the question to include both. Do you know what the problem might be then?

Comment: Did you include `C:\Users\file1\file2\file3\Python\Scripts\` in the PATH environment variable ?

Comment: @glenfant THANK YOU!!!! That just fixed it. But here is the thing, I already had C:\Users\file1\file2\file3\Python (this doesn't include the \Scripts part) in the Path environment variables, but it didn't work. I had assumed if I gave it a higher level directory that it would work for all the folders under it.